# mysql_insert_id() failed to retrieve auto increment ID

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

```
$dml = "insert into ... ";
mysql_query($dml,$con);
$Id = isset($row) ? $row['id'] : mysql_insert_id($con);
```

I saw the record is created,but just can't retrieve the Id.

What's wrong?

**EDIT**

fixed,it's caused by $row.

Comment: "...can't retrieve the Id" is too vague, please provide details - were there any errors or warnings, what was the value of $Id (notice the first capital letter - variable names are case-sensitive in php) etc.

Answer (score 2):

$row must have been be set so its never evaluating the last_insert_id() call

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the internal MySQL SQL function LAST_INSERT_ID() in an SQL query instead?

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php):

> ### **Return Values**
>
> The ID generated for an `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>   column by the previous INSERT query on
>   success, 0 if the previous query does
>   not generate an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value,
>   or FALSE if no MySQL connection was
>   established.

So, while this may seem silly, ensure that the table you are inserting your data into contains a column with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property set.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have an auto_increment on that "id", in the table you just inserted some data ?

The manual of [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id) states that :

> **Return Values** 
> The ID generated for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the
>   previous `INSERT` query on success, **0
>   if the previous query does not
>   generate an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value**, or
>   `FALSE` if no MySQL connection was
>   established.

Maybe this explains the problem ?

*If not, can you provide us with more informations ? Like the structure of the table, and/or a full insert query ?*

Comment: Oh :-( can you edit your question to add some more information, so ? Might help someone have another, better, idea ^^

Comment: The table structure is complex,and the query includes CJK characters.